# Arc length of a sine wave kinda

Tags: real-analysis, recreational-mathematics

I find myself trying to work out a formula to help in speeding up a task i do on a daily basis, but it seems to be beyond my education.

I'm trying to work out the length of a sort of sine wave that consists of 2 arcs of the same length and a straight line joining the two:

[image]

I currently draw this in CAD and tweek the "A" & "B" values to get the length of this black line to match a pre calculated length. However, I want to calculate values "A" & "B" from the line length that is pre calculated.

For example: "A" = 60mm "B" = 140mm "C" = 21mm

What would the formula be to find the length of the black Sine wave length?

In CAD this comes to 178.249mm

But I want to calculate "A" & "B" in excel so a formula is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the precise mathematical description of the 2 arcs at the ends?

Comment: The arc length of pieces of sinusoidal curves is shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine#Arc_length . Add the straight line with the usual pythagorean formula to get the length of the split black line.

Comment: Am I correct that the two end curves are arcs of circles of radius $C$? If so, the length $\ell$ of the straight line section can be found by calculating the square of the distance between the two centers by two different ways: $(2C)^2 + \ell^2 = A^2 + B^2$. Unfortunately, the length of the two circular arcs are a bit more complicated.

Comment: "C" is the radius of the to arcs Thank you guys for all your input i'm not good at higher education maths. I've looked  at "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine#Arc_length" but i could do with this braking down for me to fully understand the formula.